# AOSP: Android privilaged port, file group and starting service

Tags: android, linux, android-source

I am trying to add an http server to my custom ROM, which is based on 5.1. I managed to place `lighttpd` binary in `system/xbin` via PRODUCT_COPY_FILES in `device.mk`, and able to run it successfully in device in eng build. Server in listening to port `80`.

But in user build, server is not able to bind to `80`. When checked, file owner/group is root/shell.  Is this the reason port 80 is not allowed ? How to change to `root/root` while placing the binary ? Is there any alternative method to bind to `80` ?

EDIT-1

Another option I tried is to use iptables.. but again , permission denied. 
Is there any way to add an iptable rule in android source and build ?

Also read about 'updating linux configuration' to mark port 80 as a non-privileged port.. but could not figure out how to so this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should not leave it running as root on port 80. this may end up in a security breach.

Either run on a higher than 1024 port, or read this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166817/using-the-setuid-bit-properly) , especially the part that explains how to use su

Comment: thank you for the reply.  I have few other systems trying to connect to port 80.. hence this attempt.  Within 6 months we would be updating those to point to a higher port.
I tried via su.. but no luck. still port 80 permission is denied. Interestingly, su is also root:shell.
Looks like changing lighttpd as root:root is the only option..

Comment: if selinux is enabled on this android device. you might have to deal with that too.

Comment: I managed root:root for su with android_filesystem_config.h. Also set permission as 6755.  But to my surprise, port 80 is still not permitted.  Also, su is not able to set chown of another file in system/xbin.  
Which other aspect would be the spoil spot ? As I have mentioned, in eng build port 80 is open.
SELinux is disabled.

Comment: I am not sure that using su, or running it as root would be really different from the security view.